# C# TCP Socket file transfer chunk by chunk not working with files that are above 5mbs

Tags: c#, .net, networking

So I have this file transfer function that I made which works fine with small files but does not work with big files (above 5 or 10mbs). Basically what I do is I split the file into chunks and add a 'header' which defines what type of data it is so that the client can understand. I am also using this 'header' approach because I also want to be able to upload files and do other stuff at the same time. The problem is that the client is receiving half of the bytes even tho the server is sending all the bytes so I am assuming the header gets corrupted and `if (header == "s^")` return false.
Here is my code

Server (Uploader):

```cs
int max_buffer = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
using (var fs = new FileStream(fo_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] header = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("s^fd");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[max_buffer];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    long bytesToRead = fs.Length;
    while (bytesToRead > 0)
    {
        int n = fs.Read(buffer, 0, max_buffer);
        if (n == 0) break;
        if (n != buffer.Length)
                Array.Resize(ref buffer, n);

        byte[] data = new byte[header.Length + n];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, data, 0, header.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, data, header.Length, n);
        _client.Send(data);

        bytesRead += n;
        bytesToRead -= n;
    }
}
```

Client (Downloader):

```cs
private static MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream(); //global scope

byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int recieved = _clientSocket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
if (recieved == 0) return;
byte[] data = new byte[recieved];
Array.Copy(buffer, data, recieved);
string header = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, 4);
if (header == "s^")
{
    string header_cmd = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 4, 4);
    if (header_cmd == "fd")
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[data.Length - 32];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 32, fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        fileStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        fo_writeSize += fileBytes.Length;
        if (fo_writeSize >= fo_size) //fo_size is the file size that the server sends before sending the actual file itself
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(fo_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            fileStream.WriteTo(fs);
            fileStream.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A TCP connection is _not_ packet oriented. So if you send out a block, there's no guarantee that the receiving end receives the same block size. That means that the second packet you receive does not necessarily start with the header. You have to include the packet length in your header.

Comment: @PMF Can I please have an example? Thanks.

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol. For messages, you use a message-based protocol, e.g. UDP. Simply pass a stream to TCP, and it will deliver it. With UDP, you need to have some type of application protocol.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204406/c-sharp-tcp-file-transfer-images-semi-transferred?rq=1